# pro-guard configuration in google play

Tags: java, android, google-play, proguard

The question arose in this text I read from some  blog.

"Note that you might need to uninstall the development version of the app in your device, because the optimized APK will be signed and the dev app must be removed first."

from this blog.
http://blog.androidquery.com/2011/06/android-optimization-with-proper.html

so my question is this

I have My app on google play  , but now I want to add (pro-guard) to my app, after that modification , with the new version with (pro-guard)  the auto update  for the app with pre version (non pro-guard) still works? .

I mean if they are going to upgrade to the new version users with no problem.
To those who have the previous version.

Comment: Not really a code question but yes,  it will work.  Your newer version when posted to Play will allow users to upgrade to the newer version as BOTH apks should be signed by the same release keystore. This shouldn't bother any of your users.  DEBUG builds you push to your testing device or emulator are signed with DEBUG keystores and are typically never uploaded to the play.

Comment: I mean if they are going to upgrade to the new version users with no problem.
To those who have the previous version.

Comment: >I mean if they are going to upgrade to the new version users with no problem....Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it will still work.

The note you mention is not referring to anything regarding proguard; it is referring to the key used to sign your application.

When you hit the debug button in Eclipse or Android Studio, the APK is signed with your debug keystore (found at .android/debug.keystore). When you publish to the market, you need to sign it with your release keystore.

When you attempt to install an application, the installation will fail if the device already has an application with the same package but signed with a different keystore.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that matters for Google Play is whether you continue to sign your *release* builds with the same key. As long as you do that you're fine. You can make a release with or without Proguard enabled as you like.